# Auto-numbering each line in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to auto number each line that a user puts into a textbox and display the result in another textbox.

Turn this
`blah blah blah`
`some stuff to be numbered`
`more stuff to number`

to this
`1 blah blah blah`
`2 some stuff to be numbered`
`3 more stuff to number`

so far I have
`output.Text = Regex.Replace(input.Text, input.Text, @"{1,}+");`

But this is replacing all text with `{1,}`
I cant seem to figure out how to loop each line back after placing a number and a space.
(I am new to c#)
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be simpler to implement a non-Regex solution:

```
var numberedLines = input.Text
    .Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select ((line, index) => (index + 1) + " " + line)
    .ToArray();
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numberedLines);
output.Text = result;
```

The first line uses `string.Split()` to split up the string around line returns into an array.  Then I use LINQ `.Select` method to apply a function to each element in the array - in this case, adding line number and space at the beginning of each line (`index + 1` is necessary because the index values are 0-based).  Then I use `string.Join` method to put the array back together into a single string.

Demo: http://ideone.com/DrFTfl

---

It can actually be done with a Regular Expression if you use a `MatchEvaluator` delegate to apply  the line numbering:

```
var index = 1;
output.Text = Regex.Replace(input.Text, "^",
    (Match m) => (index++).ToString() + " ",
    RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

The pattern `^` typically matches the beginning of an expression.  However, with `RegexOptions.Multiline`, it matches the beginning of each line.  Then for replacement, I use a delegate (anonymous function) that adds `#` + space to the beginning of the line, and then increments the index counter for the next row.

Demo: http://ideone.com/9LD0ZY

Comment: When i tried to use the non-Regex solution i got a red squiggly line under  `string.Join("\n", numberedLines);` Regex solution worked fine though. any idea why non-Regex isn't working?

Comment: slight improvement: `string.Join("\r\n", input.Text.Split('\n').Select((line, lineNumber) => string.Format("{0}\t{1}", lineNumber+1, line.TrimEnd('\r'))));`

Comment: @Kazankoph: Ah.  See update with `.ToArray()`.  Apparently my local test environment has an overload that allows an `IEnumerable` to be passed to `string.Join`, but normally it requires an array.

Comment: @publicgk: How is combining everything into a single line an improvement?  I think that makes it harder to understand.

Comment: :) i should have mentioned it. It takes care of '\r\n'.  `TrimEnd('\r')`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `split` by `\r\n`, concatenate each line of the `string[]` with an incremented number and a space, and then `join` by `\r\n` ?

Comment: This simple solution is most likely the best. Perhaps, split on Environment.NewLine instead of the constant (but most likely value) of \r\n

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to C# lets keep it as simple as possible.

By the looks of it you already have all your strings. So it boils down to this:

```
        // store all lines in a list
        // ...

        var list = new List<string> {"blah", "blah2", "and some more blah"};
        var list2 = new List<string>();
        var i = 1;
        foreach (var str in list)
        {
            list2.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", i, str));
            i++;
        }

        // write contents of list2 back to wherever you want them visualized
```